# @Published Var not updating subview

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My problem is that my @Published variable isn't updating my swiftui subview.  It changes from false to true, however the view itself isn't updating.  Below I pasted a very simplified version of my problem.  Also, I passed the api variable that was created within the `FirstView` to the `SubView`, however the view still didn't change.  If this isn't enough information and you are okay with looking at the full project I can share it down below.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var Api = API()
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            SubView()
            
            Button(action:{
                Api.apicall()
            }){
                Text("search")
            }
        }
    }
    
}


struct SubView:View{
    @ObservedObject var daApi = API()
    var array = [1,2,3]
    var body: some View{
        ForEach(0..<array.count){ number in
            Text("\(number)")
        }
        if daApi.viewPresent == true{
            Text("Swag")
        }
        
        
    }
}


class API:ObservableObject{
    @Published var viewPresent:Bool = false
    
    func apicall(){
        viewPresent = true
        //The Long ApiCall
        viewPresent = false
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using two APIs. You should go watch the SwiftUI data flow videos from the past couple of WWDCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you have 2 **different** instances of `API`. You need to share the *same* instance between both `Views`:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var Api = API()
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            SubView(daApi: Api)
            
            Button(action:{
                Api.apicall()
            }){
                Text("search")
            }
        }
    }
    
}


struct SubView:View{
    @ObservedObject var daApi : API
    var array = [1,2,3]
    var body: some View{
        ForEach(0..<array.count){ number in
            Text("\(number)")
        }
        if daApi.viewPresent == true {
            Text("Swag")
        }
    }
}


class API:ObservableObject{
    @Published var viewPresent:Bool = false
    
    func apicall(){
        viewPresent = true
    }
}
```

Also, in your `apiCall`, you set `viewPresent` to `false` and then `true` immediately again, so I removed one of those.

In Swift, generally variable names start with a lowercase letter -- `Api` should probably be changed to `api`.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, it did, thank you.  I swear I already did this but I'm just stupid and this worked out.  Thanks again